# Нет доступа к интернету Windows terminal Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: windows, ubuntu, сеть, консоль

[image: вывод из консоли]

Я пробовал переустановить Ubuntu c 20.04 версии до 18.04, но интернет отсутствует.

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос (а) Версия WSL (1 или 2), (б) вывод команды `ifconfig` в Ubuntu, (в) вывод команды `ipconfig` в Windows, (г) вывод команды `route -n` в Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте перезапустить интернет демона, проверьте, работает DHCP или у вас статический IP адрес.

Сделайте ping на localhost, на шлюз, на внешний IP адрес.

Также возможна проблема с статической маршрутизацией или с фаерволом.

Много факторов.